# Youtube fails to load video

Tags: flash

I'm currently using Natty. I've used adobe's version of flash found on their website, the one found in the depository, and finally the one from sevenmachines ppa. All the flash plugins have the same issue: the video on youtube and the playback controls fail to load. The audio works just fine, as does the html page itself. Just no video, or controls.

Same issue happens on Google Chrome and in Firefox. Further making this issue strange is that it's only limited to youtube and no other video website.

Comment: Please look at this thread at [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515470)

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit or 64-bit machine? Does any flash plugin show up on the about:plugins page (Firefox)? Are you sure that you don't have an incompatible flash version laying around in `~/.mozilla/plugins`? You need to install `flashplugin-installer` or `flashplugin64-installer` if you've added the sevenmachines PPA.

Comment: Lekensteyn: I have a 64-bit machine and 64-bit Natty, and was previously running 32-bit flash (thank goodness for dpkg -i --force-architecture), now running 64-bit flash from the sevenmachines ppa since it came out, after uninstalling for the former via ubuntu's package manager.

Answer (score 2):

While nitstorm's answer might fix your problem temporarily, I suggest going another route:

[Google Chrome](http://chrome.google.com) has its own built-in, auto-updated version of chrome. Might be worth a look.

Also, if it's just YouTube videos, take a look at [YouTube HTML5 Trial](http://YouTube.com/html5). It allows you to play videos without flash.

Comment: I keep hearing that Google Chrome has its own built-in Flash, but I could never get it to work personally until I went and downloaded the plugin separately anyway.