# YouTube is not working

Tags: 12.04, flash, youtube

Why is YouTube not working? I have downloaded and installed the packages ubuntu-restricted-extras and flashplugin-installer, but Chromium says “Could not load Shockwave flash”. Is there a way to fix this? I tried downloading Google Chrome but that didn’t work. YouTube also doesn’t work on Firefox.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to install ubuntu-restricted-extras, not just download them (except if with the "i have downloaded the ubuntu restricted extras" you meant that you installed too). From terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) run `sudo apt-get install -y ubuntu-restricted-extras` stay there until installation completes, when it asks you for the MS fonts EULA, hit ENTER(key) to confirm.

Comment: yes the Extras are installed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube fails to load video](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61160/youtube-fails-to-load-video)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have flash installed. It does not come pre-installed in Ubuntu. To install it open a teminal window (ctrl + alt + t) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

If you are not familiar with using the terminal you can follow the instructions [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Flash-Player-on-Ubuntu).

Comment: i have installed that flash plugin and ubuntu restricted extras yet youtube dosent work.

Comment: @user183549 I don't have enough reputation to correct mark this as a duplicate, but I think this is a duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2544/where-is-the-flash-in-chrome). You might be able to find help there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer
```

also since you are using chromium I recommend this:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

The second one is especially important for html5 apps. Hope this helps you.